# Display result in IE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this code to determine the java values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>

  <p id="demo">Click the button to determine whether your browser has Java enabled.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">click mee </button>

 <script>
function myFunction()
{
 var x = "Java Enabled: " + navigator.javaEnabled();
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

when i click button the result will display in same browser but i want it to display in `IE` browser.

Comment: you want to display only in IE?

Comment: I think it shows in all browsers but not in IE.. is that so ?

Comment: What is the version of your IE btw?

Comment: If i understand your question then you are asking to open a ie window from firefox , is it?

Comment: Use navigator.appName to check which browser is used. It will be Microsoft Internet Explorer for IE browser

Comment: yes Mr.Max , plz help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display only in IE then use [**conditional comments**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
<!--[if IE]>
 <script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = "Java Enabled: " + navigator.javaEnabled();
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi,<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to determine whether your browser has Java enabled.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">click meeeee </button>



<!--[if IE]>
 <script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = "Java Enabled: " + navigator.javaEnabled();
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;


<![endif]-->


</body>
</html>
I sthis is write code to display